# How to deal with controller dependencies when testing directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm testing an Angular directive using the following spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('playerInfo directive', function() {
  var element;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('gameApp'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = '<player-info></player-info>';
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.digest();
  }));

  it('should replace the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    expect(element.html()).toContain('Score:');
  });
});
```

and my directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gameApp')
  .directive('playerInfo', playerInfo);

function playerInfo() {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/player/playerInfo.directive.html',
    controller: 'PlayerInfoController',
    controllerAs: 'playerInfo'
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element) {
    var address =  angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
    address.on('click', function() {
      address.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
    });
  }
}
```

The error I keep seeing is `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'moment.utc')`.

EDIT: It's not my controller causing the issue after all. I use the [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) directive twice in my directive's HTML template:

```
<div>{{playerInfo.game.date | amDateFormat: 'MMMM Do, YYYY'}} - <b am-time-ago="playerInfo.game.date"></b></div>
```

This seems to be causing the error, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I have added both `src/assets/bower_components/moment/moment.js` and `src/assets/bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js` to the `files` array of `karma.config.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the order in which I declared necessary files in `karma.config.js`. `moment` NEEDS to come before `angular-moment`:

```
files: [
  ...
  'src/assets/bower_components/moment/moment.js',
  'src/assets/bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js',
  ...
],
```